# How to add event listeners to create-react-app default sw.js file

Tags: reactjs, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I want to use the default service-worker (`sw.js`) file of `Create-React-App` module.

sw.js file looks like the following code:

```
const isLocalhost = Boolean(
  window.location.hostname === 'localhost' ||
    window.location.hostname === '[::1]' ||
    window.location.hostname.match(
      /^127(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}$/
    )
);

export function register(config) {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' && 'serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    console.log('[Service Worker] Service Worker Registered!');
    const publicUrl = new URL(process.env.PUBLIC_URL, window.location.href);
    if (publicUrl.origin !== window.location.origin) {
      return;
    }

    window.addEventListener('load', () => {
      const swUrl = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/service-worker.js`;

      if (isLocalhost) {
        checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl, config);

        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(() => {
          console.log(
            'hello'
          );
        });
      } else {
        registerValidSW(swUrl, config);
      }
    });

  }
}

function registerValidSW(swUrl, config) {
  navigator.serviceWorker
    .register(swUrl)
    .then(registration => {
      registration.onupdatefound = () => {
        const installingWorker = registration.installing;
        if (installingWorker == null) {
          return;
        }
        installingWorker.onstatechange = () => {
          if (installingWorker.state === 'installed') {
            if (navigator.serviceWorker.controller) {
              console.log(
                'link'
              );

              if (config && config.onUpdate) {
                config.onUpdate(registration);
              }
            } else {
              console.log('Content is cached for offline use.');

              if (config && config.onSuccess) {
                config.onSuccess(registration);
              }
            }
          }
        };
      };
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error);
    });
}

function checkValidServiceWorker(swUrl, config) {
  fetch(swUrl)
    .then(response => {
      const contentType = response.headers.get('content-type');
      if (
        response.status === 404 ||
        (contentType != null && contentType.indexOf('javascript') === -1)
      ) {

        navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => {
          registration.unregister().then(() => {
            window.location.reload();
          });
        });
      } else {
        registerValidSW(swUrl, config);
      }
    })
    .catch(() => {
      console.log(
        'No internet connection found. App is running in offline mode.'
      );
    });
}

export function unregister() {
  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(registration => {
      registration.unregister();
    });
  }
}
```

What I want is to add some more event listener to this file, I have tried different part of the above code to add listeners but it doesn't work! As an example I added the following, but I don't know where it should be placed to work properly:

```
window.addEventListener('fetch', (e){
    console.log('[service worker] fetch')
})
```

The other events are `install`, `activate`, `beforeinstallprompt` and etc.

> My main purpose of asking this question is to understand how to add install banner to my react project!

Comment: In order to get your main purpose, you can add just ```window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', (e) => {``` in your index.js not on serviceWorker.js but adding fetch event listener is a different story! I could do it yet! :)

Comment: @ajafari Thank you Ahmad! My problem just solved, my friend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not modify the generated service worker file in create-react-app without ejecting.. as a workaround you can create a sw-epilog.js file where you add all the service worker specific code and have a script in the package.json that appends that file to the generated service worker file as mentioned in https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5890#issuecomment-450915616

I have a gist to demonstrate this here https://gist.github.com/khaledosman/de3535c8873831153efdf6c10a4b4080 see the last two files

```
// sw-epilog.js
// Add a listener to receive messages from clients
self.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
  // Force SW upgrade (activation of new installed SW version)
  if ( event.data === 'skipWaiting' ) {
    self.skipWaiting();
  }
});
```

```
//package.json
"scripts": {
  "build": "rm -rf build/ && react-scripts build && npm run-script sw-epilog",
  "sw-epilog": "cat src/sw-epilog.js >> build/service-worker.js",
},
```

for a full implementation you can also see https://github.com/khaledosman/create-react-pwa

Comment: Thank you Khaled, Would you please give me more detail of how to do it? for example is it necessary to remove the sw.js file from my directory or not? and then how to register it the service worker to navigator?

Comment: @MostafaGhadimi the sw.js file created by create-react-app is not the real service worker file the browser uses, it takes care of registering th service worker and listening to its lifecycle updates, the real service worker file is generated by a webpack plugin that create-react-app internally uses which is workbox plugin, the actual service worker file is then generated in build/service-worker.js, so the sw.js file you should keep as it is, or optionally configure if u want to intercept the sw lifecycle to do something, take a look at build/service-worker.js after build

Comment: You mean it is necessary to build the project? Does it have a another way to test it in developing mode?

Comment: nope, one of the requirements of service workers is that they need to be served over https (localhost is an exception), To test locally what I personally do is
`npm i -g serve`
`npm run build`
`cd build/ && serve`

The code snippet I shared above shows a notification to the user that the app has been updated with a button to update, otherwise the service worker will only update itself when all tabs where the app is running are closed and the app is reopened see https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/making-a-progressive-web-app